# Rich Text area field

Tags: richtextarea, file-storage, data-storage, storage-limit

We have a requirement to upload before and after pictures, can we use rich text area field ? Which storage category does Rich text area field comes into - data storage or file storage ?

Comment: Something else worth noting in addition to Eric's answer: I believe Rich Text Fields default image width to 500 px wide, and don't give you a way to resize images. You may find this makes your images too small for your liking - in which case you might consider an alternative like hosting the images online and referencing via a formula field with an `Image()` method and URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Help docs seem to answer all your questions:

> The maximum size of an image that can be uploaded in a rich text area
>   field is 1 MB. Only .gif, .jpg, and .png file types are supported.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_using_rich_text_area.htm

> Images within the rich text area fields count towards file storage for
>   the object that contains the field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XL-Connector](https://www.xappex.com/docs/enabler4excel/basic-features/installing-enabler/) to mass upload/download images to Rich Text Area fields.

Simply paste pictures into cells and run the Update or Insert DML operation to upload.
Simply run a SOQL query to download.